Assigning Macro to a Button
I've created the following simple macro generating dates from given inputs in an Excel sheet:

Sub Date1()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Range("Input!$C$14").Value
LastDate = Range("Input!$C$15").Value

If Day(FirstDate) <> 1 Then
FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(FirstDate), Month(FirstDate), 1)
End If

NextDate = FirstDate
Range("Output!B5").Select

Do Until NextDate >= LastDate
ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
NextDate = DateAdd("m", 1, NextDate)

Loop

End Sub

When I run it manually, it works fine. Once I assign it to a button using the developer tab, however, it doesn't work anymore. The button is on a different sheet than where the macro's output is supposed to go.
I've already tried using msgbox to see if the macro has been called, and it has. The only explanation I can come up with is that something with my macro is not working. I would appreciate any kind of help.

When programming VBA for Excel, you should say goodbye to using Select, Selection and ActiveCell. You can use a Worksheet without activating it and you can read and write from/to cells or ranges without selecting them first. But you should always tell VBA what to use (eg which sheet you want to use). This makes you code not only faster, but more reliable.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input") will explicitely refer to the sheet "Input" of the workbook where the code lives. The With-statement is just a shortcut, you could also write ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C14").Value
Have a look to the modified code:
Sub Date1()
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim NextDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
        FirstDate = .Range("C14").Value  ' You could also use .Cells(14, 3)
        LastDate = .Range("C15").Value
    End With

    FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(FirstDate), Month(FirstDate), 1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
        NextDate = FirstDate
        Dim row As Long
        row = 5
        Do Until NextDate >= LastDate
            .Range("C" & row).Value .= NextDate  ' Or .Cells(row, 3)
            NextDate = DateAdd("m", 1, NextDate)
            row = row + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

A remark:
When something is not working as expected, use the VBA debugger. This enables you to execute your code step by step and watches what is going on. Also, you can use the statement Debug.Print to dump some information into the immediate window - open it with Ctrl+G.
In your case, I can imagine the following issues with your code

The active workbook may be a different one
You read invalid date values and therefore the Do-Loop is never executed.
Range("Output!B5").Select fails and therefore ActiveCell doesn't change, resulting in writing the data into different cells as you expect.

For further reading, take the time and read How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
To learn some basics about the debugger, watch for example Master VBA Debugging in 20 Minutes

Thank you. I am quite new to VBA, so I wasn't aware that usage of select function is not advised. I've tried compiling your code and it worked. If you don't mind, I have a follow-up question: I'm trying to implement an Active X Button calling the abovementioned sub, however, nothing happens when I call it. Might that have to do with the select function as well?

You should at first try to check if the button triggers any code at all (eg by setting a breakpoint to the top of the routine). If that's not the case, you have an issue with the event handler. Easiest way to create an event handler is to place the button and double click it - it will create the event routine. The event routine itself should have only one line of code: Call your Date1-routine.

And just an advice: ActiveX controls are not very popular because they have several issues. Either use Form Controls, or place a rect shape on the sheet and assign a Macro to it (just right click on it).

Try changing the syntax of your "Range" functions from Range("Input!$C$14").Value to Worksheets("Input").Range("$C$14")

I've tried avoiding this entirely by adding the range functions to the name manager. Furthermore, I added Worksheets("Output").Select before the loop. Out of 10 times trying the button, the macro has now been called 2. Any ideas on how to get it running smoothly?

The function you want is Worksheets("Output").Activate.  Using the syntax I referenced above is the correct way to do this.  Explicitly declare everything.  Never rely on VBA to interpret what you think it should be doing and instead tell it EXACTLY what you want it to do.  In these kind of cases I use a "With" clause to avoid having to retype the Workboook reference every time.  Even the ActiveCell can be questionable at times, since it can be changed as your code progresses.  Create a Range variable to store the range of the ActiveCell and use that in your code.
